# How to turn a list of lists into a single string in grid format?

Tags: python

I'm making a game which is like a maze game, where you control a player through the terminal by typing in custom direction commands. I'm up to the part where I have to turn a list of lists of cells into a single string in a grid format so I can basically store the game's map.

For example:

```
ls = [[" * ", " ", " * ", " * ", " * "], [" * ", " ", " * ", " * ", " * "], [" * ", " * ", " ", " * ", " * "], [" * ", " * ", " ", " * ", " * "]]
```

Convert it into a single grid formatted string

```
some_string = 
                * ***

                *  **

                ** **
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate the list and join as a string and add newlines as you go.

```
ls = [[" * ", " ", " * ", " * ", " * "], [" * ", " ", " * ", " * ", " * "], [" * ", " * ", " ", " * ", " * "], [" * ", " * ", " ", " * ", " * "]]
some_str = ''
for l in ls:
    some_str += ''.join(l) + '\n'
```

```
 *  *  *  * 
 *  *  *  * 
 *  *  *  * 
 *  *  *  *
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing it like this, this is an O(n^2) operation, in this case it will be fine because the strings are short

Comment: `join(ls)` and `join(a for a in ls)` has exactly the same complexity.

Comment: I'm not talking about that, I'm talking about the string concatenation, that's an O(n) operation, and you're doing it N times

Comment: If by `N` you mean the length of each sub-list, then there are N^2 stars or characters in total. You can never do things better than O(N^2). Can you?

Comment: N is the length of the final string, you can do O(n)

Comment: On that point you're definitely right, `join` would be faster, but for such an example it seemed more intuitive. Anyway, won't disagree `join` would've been better, but I'll keep this just for readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your map in a single string of length 20. For accessing the grid, you can use (i * 5 + j) for each place in grid.

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop will do this:

```
ls = [[" * ", " ", " * ", " * ", " * "], [" * ", " ", " * ", " * ", " * "], [" * ", " * ", " ", " * ", " * "], [" * ", " * ", " ", " * ", " * "]]
some_str = ''

for i in range (len(ls)):
    some_str+="".join(ls[i])+'\n'
print(some_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `join` when doing this, as it's more pythonic:

```
some_string = '\n'.join(''.join(l) for l in ls)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls = [["*","*"],["*","*"]]
lines = [" ".join(row) for row in ls]
grid = "\n".join(lines) # "\n" new line
```

Convert cells in the same row to lines 
convert lines to grid.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but try this:

```
grid_string=""

for sublist in ls:
    grid_string += "".join(sublist)+"\n"

print(grid_string)
```